# Why is the function not working in React for chess?

Tags: reactjs

When using the *react-chessboard* and *chessboard.js* libraries, the following code is not working for me. Why?

```
import {useState} from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import {Chess} from "chess.js";
    import {Chessboard} from "react-chessboard";

    function App() {

      const [game, setGame] = useState(new Chess());
      console.log(game);

      function changeGame(move){
        const gameCopy = {...game};
        const result = gameCopy.move(move);
        setGame(gameCopy);
        return result;
      }

      function makeRandomMove() {
        const possibleMoves = game.moves();
        if (game.game_over() || game.in_draw() || possibleMoves.length === 0)
          return; // exit if the game is over
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleMoves.length);
        changeGame(possibleMoves[randomIndex]);
      }

      function onDrop(source, target){
        const move = changeGame({
          from: source,
          to: target,
          promotion: "q",
        });

        if (move === null){
          return false;
        }
        setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 200);
        return true;
      }

      return(
      <div className="board">
        <Chessboard position={game.fen()} onPieceDrop={onDrop} />
      </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

This is the error message I get when I try and make a move on the board itself:

gameCopy.move is not a function

```
TypeError: gameCopy.move is not a function
    at changeGame (http://localhost:3000/main.bfd829889e267496a27d.hot-update.js:38:29)
    at onDrop (http://localhost:3000/main.bfd829889e267496a27d.hot-update.js:49:18)
    at handleSetPosition (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12422:11)
    at Object.B [as drop] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12694:115)
    at nt.drop (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10592:26)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9383:25
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9388:10
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at F.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9380:7)
    at n.<computed> [as drop] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9491:21)
```

Comment: Can you try changing import to `import Chess from "chess.js";` as shown in doc https://github.com/Clariity/react-chessboard#basic-example?

Comment: I tried import Chess from "chess.js" but I have the same error

Comment: Why don't you just use `game.move()` instead of the copy?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are using chess.js version ^0.12.0, your code will code will work exactly as is.

Answer (score -3):

The error you're encountering, "gameCopy.move is not a function," is happening because you are trying to call the move method on an object created with {...game}, which is a shallow copy of the game object. Shallow copying doesn't work well for objects with methods, as it only copies the references to those methods, not the methods themselves.

To fix this issue, you should create a deep copy of the game object using a library like Lodash's cloneDeep or by manually copying all relevant properties. Here's how you can do it using cloneDeep:

First, make sure you have Lodash installed. If not, you can install it using:

bash

```
npm install lodash
```

Then, modify your code like this:

javascript

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Chess } from 'chess.js';
import { Chessboard } from 'react-chessboard';
import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep'; // Import cloneDeep from Lodash

function App() {
  const [game, setGame] = useState(new Chess());
  console.log(game);

  function changeGame(move) {
    const gameCopy = cloneDeep(game); // Create a deep copy of the game object
    const result = gameCopy.move(move);
    setGame(gameCopy);
    return result;
  }

  function makeRandomMove() {
    const possibleMoves = game.moves();
    if (game.game_over() || game.in_draw() || possibleMoves.length === 0) return;
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleMoves.length);
    changeGame(possibleMoves[randomIndex]);
  }

  function onDrop(source, target) {
    const move = changeGame({
      from: source,
      to: target,
      promotion: 'q',
    });

    if (move === null) {
      return false;
    }
    setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 200);
    return true;
  }

  return (
    <div className="board">
      <Chessboard position={game.fen()} onPieceDrop={onDrop} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

By This You can fix the issue. Any other problem just comment down :)

Comment: This is wrong.  You never "copy a method".  You always just make another reference to the method.

Comment: You're absolutely right. When you create a copy of an object in JavaScript using methods like the spread operator or Object.assign(), you're not duplicating the methods themselves. Instead, both the original object and the copy refer to the same methods in memory. Any changes made to these methods in either the original or the copy will affect both because they share the same function references.

Comment: Now I get this error:
game.game_over is not a function
TypeError: game.game_over is not a function
    at makeRandomMove (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46:14)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: My question and comments are not from chatgpt?

Comment: @MukeshArvindhParanthaman Sorry, I'm guessing that NotTheDr01ds was directing that comment at the user that posted this answer, not you.

Comment: What chatGPT I have written this comment by my own, I know english quite well. What is the matter in this?